# Best Buy API most 'relevant' or 'best match' query?

Tags: php, api, best-buy-api

I'm working with the Best Buy API (http://developer.bestbuy.com, http://api.bestbuy.com/v1/) and I can't seem to find anything about product searches returning the most relevant results. I have API integrations with other marketplaces, Amazon, Ebay, etc and they all return results based on relevance.

Example Best Buy API query is:

```
http://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(name=iphone*)?format=json...
```

I actually switched over to this wild card search on the name because keyword search was giving me everything under the sun matching 'iphone' and nothing relevant in the first batch of results - name = 'iphone*' was a bit better...

What I would expect is to see actual iphones in the first batch of results - which is what I see with my other API integrations by default. Best Buy responded to me on Twitter that I should use their 'Category API' to narrow the results. Translation: I need to guess which category the user means when they enter a search term...?

I suppose I could do that, but ***why?*** I think Best Buy should offer that up as a 'relevance' option or something similar to what they have on their homepage search of 'Best Match' in the sort.

Does anyone know if I'm missing something here? I actually did humor them and look at the category api thinking that maybe I could issue search to the service with 'iphone' and get back the most relevant category and *then* do a product search with a categoryid, but nothing there like that.

At current my best chance is to search based on a name wildcard search...and then sort by price descending *cringe* - or heaven forbid, come up with some kind of searchterm-to-categoryid relationship on my side which I do not want to do.

Anyone tried to work this out yet? Thanks!

Comment: "I think Best Buy should offer that up as a 'relevance' option or something similar to what they have on their homepage search of 'Best Match' in the sort." Sounds like you should bring this up with the Best Buy API team.

Comment: Yes, I'm already pushing this through my Twitter conversation with them. I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything or there's some way that others have solved it that makes sense I'm missing.

Comment: Did you solved it? @Dave E